# some bytes have been replaced with the unicode subsitution character

Tags: unicode, file-recovery, source-code, easeus-partition-manager

I've recently used a software called `EaseUs` to resize my volumes and although the volume had plenty of free space it succeeded to ruin the operating system and damage source files!

Some of the source files has been damaged and when I'm trying to open them with `visual studio`, I'll get the following error.

> some bytes have been replaced with the unicode subsitution character

Opening files with `notepad` doesn't help. Please let me know if there is anyway to recover them. Since it seems to have the same structure it once had.

```
var data = (await ZCodeRepository.GetResellers())
    .Where(condition)
    .Select(x => new
    {
       "  <

�
      � &�4�I!B"  H ?;"� F-=� 
x�� H

!� ^
    C!
```

Comment: Restore from your backups (you do have backups, right?)

Comment: Yes, I do, but that would be costly. They're not much new. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: I suspect that might be your only option.